# How to use Angular directive wrapped into CKEditor widget

Tags: angularjs, widget, ckeditor, directive

We use Angular directives to render data into CKEditor for a project.I have created widget that uses the directive as template, but it does not render anything into the field.Please help!
Thank you in advance!

Widget source:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('grid', {
requires: 'widget',
init: function(editor) {

    editor.widgets.add('grid', {
        template: '<div class="widget"> <div table-Directive></div> </div>',
        upcast: function(element) {
            return (element.name == 'div' && element.hasClass('widget'));
        },
        allowedContent: 'div[*]'
    });

    editor.ui.addButton('grid', {
        label: 'Demo',
        command: 'grid',
    });
}
```

});

Directive source:

```
define(['angular','js/controller/table-controller'],
  function(angular) {
  'use strict';

  angular
   .module('todoApp.table-directive', ['todoApp.table-controller'])
   .directive('tableDirective', [tableDirective]);

 function tableDirective() {
   var directive = {
     controller: 'TableController',
     templateUrl: 'template/tableDirective.html',
   };
   return directive;
 }
});
```

Edit:
In fact you can use angular component inside ckeditor, you just need to compile it by yourself using $compile.
Here I attach simple code illustrating

```
// temporarily remove data-widget attribute sets by CKEditor before $compile()
// because angular thinks that data-widget is the same directive as widget
// and applies the directive twice
var dataWidget = element.getAttribute('data-widget');
element.removeAttribute('data-widget');
// use the scope of the closest parent that has a scope
var editorScope = $(editor.container.$).closest('.idoc-editor').isolateScope();
var compiledElement = application.$compile(element)(editorScope);
// $compile replaces the compiled element (instead of only decorating it)
// and this breaks the base CKEditor widget (this.element doesn't point to the
// correct element after $compile
this.element = new CKEDITOR.dom.node(compiledElement[0]);
this.element.$.setAttribute('data-widget', dataWidget);
```

Comment: Can't help without code.

Comment: simple code has been added

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't insert angular js code in ckeditor, ckeditor is executed in an iframe and the angular scripts are not loaded in this iframe.

But in a ckeditor widget you can use ajax request to interact with your server